# Scroll Bar Suddenly not working in my page

Tags: html, css, css-float, positioning

Here is the site i am building from scratch.  Suddenly at one point browser scroll bar disappears.  How to fix it??
[***MY WEBSITE***](http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/portfolio/)

Use (ctrl + (+)) OR (ctrl + (-)) to zoom in or zoom out the website.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Its because you're possitioning your element using `fixed` when you could achieve the same layout with better div placements.

Comment: `-1` for the missing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you have a lot of things that are position: fixed;

If you are doing this from scratch... I suggest you start over. I built [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/Q3QBE/) in jsfiddle in 3 minutes. This is how you would build a site like this now days. This is starting mobile first as well... so with some media queries and a responsive slider, you should have a much more solid foundation. I hope it is helpful. Fixed positioning pulls the content out of flow and then the browser doesn't see how "long" it is, and therefore removes the need for scrolling. As you using dream weaver or something? If so, I can see how this happened. You should probably go with an html 5 doctype as well. Take a deep breath and rethink this.

HTML

```
<header class="global-header">
    <div class="inner-w">
        HEADER
    </div> <!-- .inner-w -->
</header>

<section class="main-content">
    <div class="inner-w">

        <div class="block">block</div>

        <div class="block">block</div>

        <div class="block">block</div>

    </div> <!-- .inner-w -->
</section> <!-- .main-content -->
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.global-header {
    width: 100%;
    float left;
    min-height: 150px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.main-content {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.inner-w {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 900px;
}

.block {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #f06;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I heard HTML 5 doesn't works on all browsers well.  Though i am designing my portfolio i wanted it to work on all browsers.  so i am using html 4

Comment: html5 is not just one thing. It is a bunch of things. When people say that, they mean you can't use data storage or this or that fancy piece of html5. A simple way to ensure that your website works on all browsers would be to use html5 and just don't use any of the fancy stuff. Use <div class="header"></div> instead of <header class="global-header"></header> - and you will be fine. Think about the future. You are building a website for the next 4 year, not 4 years ago. If your website is a design portfolio, I suggest you keep it up to date, as I wouldn't trust anyone with outdated code.

Comment: Also, we highly recommend replacing your id's with classes and saving your id's purely for javascript hooks and special occasions. Any way - 4 people answered your question. Your website isn't scrolling because you don't have a clear understanding of how the box model works.  Check out this explanation --- http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/ --- and go ahead and mark one of these answers as correct. Have fun! Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou very much man.  Really a nice time spent on reading your answers.  I will just change my site to HTML 5 soon.

Answer (score 1):

Don't Use `position: fixed` on everything. It takes them out of the flow of document. Use `position: fixed` for top blue banner if you want. But for rest, remove it. This will set it to `position: static` (default) which will solve the scroll problem

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely wrong way to post a question.
But, I firebugged your site and found out that every thing has `fixed position`, that is the reason you don't have the scrollbar. use `relative` position

Comment: 'position: absolute` won't help either as it also removes element from document flow.